# In Swedish, how did the third person plural pronoun de come to be pronounced /dɔm/?

Tags: swedish

The Swedish third person plural pronoun has the nominative case form *de*, which is pronounced /dɔm/.

How did this situation come about? My guess is that the nominative merged with the accusative but somehow maintained its old orthographic form.

Comment: Why don't you ask on a Swedish linguistics website?

Comment: This is a general question relating to why this situation came about in Swedish but not in Danish or Bokmål. Why not ask it here?

Comment: [History behind de/dem](https://youtu.be/ld9ieozJ-ws)

Comment: @MujjinGun This is the answer, and well documented too. If you elaborated this into an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: @jogloran [It is the situation with Bokmål too](http://www.sprakradet.no/Vi-og-vart/Publikasjoner/Spraaknytt/Arkivet/Eldre/Naa_skal_jeg_skrive_litt_om_du/): "bare skriftlig bokmål som fremdeles insisterer på skillet mellom *de* og *dem*, men både nynorsk og alt norsk talemål bruker *dei*, *de* eller *dem* både som subjektsform og objektsform" "Only written Bokmål still insists on differentiating *de* and *dem*, but both Nynorsk and the spoken language use *dei*, *de* (/di/) or *dem* as both the subject and object form."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MujjinGun has provided [this excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld9ieozJ-ws) in a comment, but it's been long enough since it was posted that it deserves a proper answer. I've provided comparisons from English as well whenever possible.

Originally, the Swedish third-person plural pronoun was *de* in the nominative and *dem* in the accusative, pronounced just as spelled. At this point the spelling was standardized, and there was much rejoicing.

Over time the pronunciation shifted to /di/ and /dɔm/, but the spelling remained the same. (Compare the mess that is modern English vowels; the spelling used to make sense, but the pronunciation has changed and the orthography hasn't kept up with it.)

Then in northern and central Sweden, *de* slowly fell out of fashion in the spoken language. Instead, *dem* was used for both the nominative and the accusative. (Compare how English *thou* has been replaced almost entirely with *you*.)

This was seen as vulgar, lower-class, and slang-y. So it happened exclusively in spoken language; in writing, and in more formal environments, the nominative would still be *de*. (Compare informal English contractions like "gonna". I'd almost always say "gonna" out loud, but in writing I would put "going to" without even noticing the difference.)

This "incorrect" pronunciation slowly spread. Once it was part of the Stockholm local dialect the vulgar/informal labels started to fade away, and by the mid-20th century /dɔm/ became the official standard pronunciation for both nominative and accusative.

And that's where we are now, with the pronouns usually spelled *de* and *dem* but both pronounced /dɔm/.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that the [Bouba/kiki effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect) has something to do with the explanation.

I'm from Northern Sweden and briefly watched and listened to the video about the de/dem/dom etymology. I think that there was absolutely nothing about why and only observations how words evolved and changed and how people did.

I would say that the reason is the sound. It is easier and sounds softer to say /dɔm/. The sound has a psychological association with something round and soft, compared with the other sound ("di/de(t)") that has a psychological association with something sharp and hard.

If you compare the sounds in a test, many people will make a connection between a soft sound (example "Bouba") and a round and soft shape, and they will make a connection between a "Kiki" sound and something sharp.

The first association (roundness) is associated with easygoing and the second association (sharpness) is associated with hard determinism.

Comment: This is pure speculation, or do you have any references for this theory?

Comment: There should be a reference. I'm researching it in Sweden and asking now among native Swedes. They say a lot about what is the correct pronunciation and almost nothing about the reasons.

Comment: The problem is that native Swedes have absolutely no idea about the history of Swedish, so your efforts are wasted.

Comment: @user6726 I guess you mean "most native Swedes"? There must be Swedes who can explain the reasons to Dac.